# CouchDb/CouchBase: Can you derive a Kimball SCD scheme via a MapReduce view?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, couchdb, cloudant

Suppose you have a log-like collection of documents in CouchDB, as in this tabulated representation of JSON documents and attributes (each row is a JSON document, each column is an attribute):

```
PRODUCT_ID START_DATE PRICE
0000000001 2016-01-01 100.00
0000000002 2016-01-01 100.00
0000000003 2016-01-01 100.00
0000000001 2016-01-02 100.00
0000000002 2016-01-02 200.00
0000000003 2016-01-02 100.00
0000000001 2016-01-03 100.00
0000000002 2016-01-03 200.00
0000000003 2016-01-03 100.00
```

Is it possible via a MapReduce View, to produce a schema implementing [Ralph Kimball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Kimball)'s Slowly Changing Dimension concept?

e.g.:

```
PRODUCT_ID START_DATE PRICE  END_DATE
0000000001 2016-01-01 100.00 2999-12-31
0000000002 2016-01-01 100.00 2016-01-02
0000000003 2016-01-01 100.00 2999-12-31
0000000002 2016-01-02 200.00 2999-12-31
```

I'm using Cloudant, which has a few enhancements over base CouchDB.

Related (much broader) question: [Data warehousing principles and NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234051/data-warehousing-principles-and-nosql/27242695)

Answer (score 0):

In CouchDB, the `/database/_all_docs` view is sorted by id. If you can tolerate having the view results in two consecutive rows per desired result, this is just a default in CouchDB.

It should be easy enough to coalesce the two rows into one for your application.

If you need more calculation on the doc values, you can create a custom view that works in the same way, using `emit(doc._id)` as your key: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html